# dynamically select an array by a string, to then .map() over it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's assume this is all passed around dynamically for the sake of argument. But the short hand is for examples sake..

```
let myVar = "something"

let anything = [{abc: 123, def: 456},{abc: 123, def: 456}]
let nothing = [{abc: 123, def: 456},{abc: 123, def: 456}]
let something = [{abc: 123, def: 456},{abc: 123, def: 456}]
let everything = [{abc: 123, def: 456},{abc: 123, def: 456}]
```

Now I would assume I could access it through square brackets but it doesn't work like for me it seems. Example

```
[myVar].map(function(k,v){...})
```

The hope for the above line is to use the string thats dynamically generated through user choices. Would reach the otherwise defined array, or translate into the equivilant of

```
something.map(function(k,v){...})
```

Comment: This doesn't work simply because  you're not defining a list where "something" is a key. You're defining variables, not lists. Could you give more context as to why you want to index "something", or what your goal is in a less abstract example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work that way, to get array using brackets you need to have parent object for that arrays, for example:

```
let myVar = "something"

let myObj = {
  anything: [{abc: 123, def: 456},{abc: 123, def: 456}],
  nothing: [{abc: 123, def: 456},{abc: 123, def: 456}],
  something: [{abc: 123, def: 456},{abc: 123, def: 456}],
  everything: [{abc: 123, def: 456},{abc: 123, def: 456}]
}

myObj[myVar].map(function(k,v){...})
```

Comment: I see the error of my ways, thank you. More coffee was needed at that point :-)